# print n to n columns in bash from a file

Tags: bash, awk

I have thousands of columns delimited by whitespace.  I want to do something similar to

```
awk '{print$1" "$2}' file
```

but I need to print a range and maintain the space between them.

For example is I have a file with the contents:

```
1.006 2.0101 1.002 3.005 0.0000 4.09873 9.0009 1000.678 15.0 0.9999 11.8
78.003 9.411 0.000 0.003 20000.0100 1.03 9.00029 100.0 0.5 123.9 1.800
```

and I want to print columns 2-3 and 6-9 I would get:

```
2.0101 1.002 4.09873 9.0009 1000.678 15.0
9.411 0.000 1.03 9.00029 100.0 0.5
```

I am open to other tools but this seems like a good one-liner in awk.

Comment: @Ed Morton o gosh you are right. I will fix this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there is one space between each field, then `cut` is the right tool for the job:

```
cut -d' ' -f 2-3,6-9 file
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually `cut` is right tool, current context its the best way to handle your job, but still if you need `awk`, you may try something like this :

```
$ cat ext_f.awk 
function ext_field(s,e, r,i)
{   if(e > s)
    {
        for(i=s; i<=e; i++)r = i > s ? r OFS $i : $i;
    }else{
        if(s!="")return $s
    }
    return r
}
{ print ext_field(2,3), ext_field(6,9) }
```

**Execution :**

***Input :***

```
$ cat file
1.006 2.0101 1.002 3.005 0.0000 4.09873 9.0009 1000.678 15.0 0.9999 11.8
78.003 9.411 0.000 0.003 20000.0100 1.03 9.00029 100.0 0.5 123.9 1.800
```

***Output :***

```
$ awk -f ext_f.awk file
2.0101 1.002 4.09873 9.0009 1000.678 15.0
9.411 0.000 1.03 9.00029 100.0 0.5
```

Suppose if you need comma or some other char as output separator, then you may modify `-v OFS=` like below

```
$ awk -v OFS="," -f ext_f.awk file
2.0101,1.002,4.09873,9.0009,1000.678,15.0
9.411,0.000,1.03,9.00029,100.0,0.5
```

If you have `gawk` then just remove below lines, from `ext_f.awk`, and use `--source` option

<s>`{ print ext_field(2,3), ext_field(6,9) }`</s>

**Example :**

```
$ awk -v OFS="," -f ext_f.awk --source '{print ext_field(1,2)}' file
1.006,2.0101
78.003,9.411
```

Comment: I will change the title to make it less exclusive to awk.  Thank you for the great explanation